# Bean validation failing after upgrade from java 7 to 8 saying : "no validator could be found for type object"

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I recently upgraded my project's java version from 7 to 8 and Spring version from 3.2.8 to 3.2.9. And now the JSR validations that used to work fine is showing errors by throwing exceptions like "no validator could be found for type object".

I am using @Max, @Min from javax.validation and @Email from hibernate validators for defining my constraints.

Is this error because of any compatibility issues ?

Comment: You have this problem with Spring 3.2.9 & Java 7? Does it work in command line?

Comment: Also which validation library version are you using? (Hibernate most likely)

Comment: The hibernate validation library version is 4.1.0. No problem  with 3.2.9 version of spring as well.

Comment: Can you try to update Hibernate Validator to the latest version and see whether the problem remains? If so, an example of your constraint usage would be helpful.

Comment: I tried updating the hibernate validator and this fixed the problem in a standalone setup. But there are some limitations in upgrading the validator version in our project.  Thanks Gunnar

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be fixed by updating the hibernate validator version to 5.2.1.

But since upgrading the validator version was not possible in my case, I debugged into the validator code further , and the root cause of this issue was pin-pointed to a java behavioral changes in reflection .
For those who are interested , please refer to the question I posted for the same : 
[Method.getAnnotations() method giving different outputs for java 1.7.0_79 and java 1.7.0_80 versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557685/method-getannotations-method-giving-different-outputs-for-java-1-7-0-79-and-ja)

In my case, I had a parent interface like

```
interface Inter {
    public String getValue();
}
```

and whenever I needed to define a constraint, I used an anonymous inner class and applied annotations on that.

```
Inter instance = new Inter() {

      @Override
      @NonNull
      public String getValue()
      { 
         return "Something";
      };
```

The issue was due to this constraint design  and the problem defined in the above link. This issue can be fixed by not making the getValue() inherited from a parent class.